# Postgres: How to use arrays as stored procedure parameters efficiently?

Tags: arrays, performance, postgresql, parameter-passing

I need to create a Postgres 9.1 PL/pgSQL stored procedure that, among other parameters, takes a sequence of values that directly reference values in one of my database columns. As far as I can tell, the canonical way to do this in Postgres is an [array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html).

This is a rather basic task, of course. My problem is scalability: My code basically works, but performs badly once the sequences passed in get large (as in a few hundreds or thousands of values):

Even rather simple SELECT statements within my stored procedure using the array in the form

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM   <some tables>
WHERE  <some other select criteria>
AND    <column with values selected by array parameter>
         IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(<array parameter>))
```

take several seconds to execute even though the database is not very large yet and there are only tens of values in the array.

My first suspicion was that `unnest(...)` is the problem, but selecting only from the table with the column referenced in the array parameter is really fast:

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM   <table with column ref'd in array parameter>
WHERE  <column with values selected by array parameter>
         IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(<array parameter>))
```

only takes a few milliseconds.

**My questions**:

1. Is there an alternative to using an array as parameter ?
2. How can I make my queries perform better ?

Comment: Post the `explain` output for both queries and show what is the other filter criteria as well as relevant schema data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make my queries perform better ?

I would expect faster performance if you rewrite your query

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM   <some tables>
WHERE  <some other select criteria>
AND    <column with values selected by array parameter>
         IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(<array parameter>));
```

to:

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM   (SELECT unnest(<array parameter>) AS param) x
JOIN   <filtered table>  ON <filter column> = x.param
JOIN   <other table> ON <join criteria>
WHERE  <some other select criteria>;
```

It sounds like the query planner chooses a suboptimal plan, misjudging the cost of your other `WHERE` criteria in comparison to the IN clause. By transforming it to an explicit `JOIN` clause you should get a better query plan.

Generally, `JOIN`s tend to be faster than large `IN` clauses in PostgreSQL.

---

> Is there an alternative to using an array as parameter ?

Yes.
You could create temporary table, fill it and run a query joining against it.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x(id int);

INSERT INTO x VALUES
(1), (2), (17), (18);

SELECT <some columns>
FROM   x
JOIN   <filtered table>  ON <filter column> = x.id
JOIN   <other table> ON <join criteria>
WHERE  <some other select criteria>;
```

Or, faster yet, use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) for the same purpose:

```
WITH x(id) AS (
    VALUES (1::int), (2), (17), (18) -- type-cast on first element is enough
    )
SELECT <some columns>
FROM   x
JOIN   <filtered table>  ON <filter column> = x.id
JOIN   <other table> ON <join criteria>
WHERE  <some other select criteria>;
```

As long as you want to use a function, an array parameter, unnested inside would be my choice, too. You could also use the CTE in my last example inside a function, just with unnest(arr) instead of a VALUES clause.

Comment: That's some great advice, thank you very much! I will try to make time to run some benchmark tests to compare the different approaches and post the results here.